# material icon ligatures not working with Pug

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pug, angular-material

I am using Pug and angular / angular material to work on a project of mine. Since it will use the material design styles it will need the material icons. It is supposed to work like this:

`<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>`

But for some reason the 'icons' just show up as italic text. (the text being "chevron_left" or whatever ofcourse)

Here is my nav.pug:

```
nav
    md-toolbar(class="md-whiteframe-z1")
        div(class="md-toolbar-tools")
            md-button(class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Menu" ng-hide="user.logged==false")
                i(class="material_icons") menu
            md-button(class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Menu" ng-hide="user.logged==true")
                i(class="material-icons") chevron_left

            h2(md-truncate flex) login

            md-button(class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More")
                i(class="material_icons") more_vert
```

And here is how it outputs the lines with the icons in it:

`<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Menu" ng-hide="user.logged==false"><i class="material_icons">menu</i></md-button>`

The weird thing in this mess is that it not only shows the menu and more icons as italic text, If I switch `user.logged` to `false` it shows the `chevron_right` properly as an icon.

I'm sorry if anything is unclear, or if this has been asked before. I did not find any useful answers. It did work before I was using Pug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this. Since I couldn't seem to get it to work this way I used the `md-icon` with a SVG path. I just downloaded the SVG files from [material.io](http://material.io) and placed them in a folder and then used this HTML:

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="icons/android.svg" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
```

Or this pug:

```
md-icon(md-svg-src="icons/android.svg" aria-label="android ")
```

and that seemed to work. hope it may help someone else someday. Just don't rely on the ligatures since it may not always work (mostly for IE browsers)

Whever I start using mdIconProvider I might update this answer to help out some more people

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found out that I forgot to add a link for google font icons

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```